Visual Studio 2022 could not find custom build tool
I am trying to create Csharp wrapper using SWIG to connect to C++ code.
I have created a .i interface file containing the reference to all header files.
How to get the compile command when right clicking on a .interface file.  This is not shown in Visual Studio 2022.  When I right click on .i file and click properties it just shows Advanced and Misc options.
